# Creating an excel file using T-SQL code with a 32 bit driver on a 64 bit SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jet

I am trying to create an Excel file using SQL queries (64 bit) using a 32 bit driver. There are a lot of links/articles online that say this is only possible once I install the 64 bit version of the Access/Jet engine.

As I can't install the 64 bit version of the Access/Jet engine, is there any way to make the query run in a 32 bit runtime environment?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with sql-server?

Comment: @MJH I am using a 64 bit version of sql-server to create an excel file.

Comment: You mention "the access database" in your question and have the "jet" tag.  Can you edit your question to make it clear what you are doing?

Comment: @MJH My mistake. Thank You.

Comment: Your access engine has to match SQL Server version. Both have to be either 32-bit or 64-bit. If your SQL Server is 64-bit version, you have to install 64-bit version of access/jet engine. Like you said, there are many articles on that.

Comment: You can look into other options to get query result into Excel other than with SQL Code.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic My question was if there is a workaround that lets you run the query regardless of the difference in the version. The reason i ask this is because the SSIS packages can run when you check the `run in 32 bit` check box. I want to do it only using SQL code.

Comment: You can insert the result of query into global ##temp table, and connect Excel to it to read from.. or you can use Import/Export wizard where you would set your query as source and Excel as target (which is basically a SSIS package)... but no `run in 32 bit` check box...

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I was talking about the checkbox which is applicable when you put the ssis job in a SQL job. I can also create a SSRS package which is the best approach. Sadly, I want to do it using only code. Are you saying this is impossible?

Comment: @TheNoob This is a good question. I have used the  `OPENROWSET` function to do this in the past and I don't think it is possible to add a parameter that allows the query to run in a 32bit environment.